# Need help proving something ultimately about a null sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

Disclaimer: I'm typing from my phone so it'll look ugly, whatever I type.

Let (Xn) be a sequence of positive numbers for which ((X(n+1))/(Xn)) is a null sequence. 
Prove that there is some positive real number c for which Xn is less than or equal to (c/(2^n)) ultimately. 
I've chosen the epsilon 1/2, but I'm getting confused as to where I am to introduce a "c". Any advice will help big time, thanks.

EDIT: We have not yet gone over any tests of convergence with infinite series. Just definitions of null, convergent, ultimately, etc. It's really early on for us :|

Comment: Just to notify you, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x_n$ is such a sequence. Let $y_n = 2^n x_n$. Note that,
$$\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n} = 2 \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \rightarrow 0.$$
Thus, by the ratio test, we have the following convergent infinite series:
$$c := \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n < \infty.$$
Because the terms in the sum are positive, we have $y_n \le c$ for all $n$. Thus, $2^n x_n \le c$, which implies $x_n \le 2^{-n} c$ for all $n$, as required.

EDIT: We don't really need series convergence (although, I like how elegant it is), just boundedness of the sequence $y_n$. Since $\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n} \rightarrow 0$, choosing $\varepsilon = 1$, there must be some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ for which

$$n \ge N \implies \frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n} < 1 \implies y_{n+1} \le y_n.$$

That is, after a while, the sequence must be decreasing. We can choose

$$c:= \max \lbrace y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_N \rbrace.$$

Then for all $n$, either $n < N$, in which case $y_n$ is part of the maximum formula, so $y_n \le c$, or $n \ge N$, so $y_n \le y_N \le c$. Either way, $y_n \le c$, so $x_n \le 2^{-n} c$.